# How to save in a variable significance of a coefficient estimated by OLS using statsmodels in python?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I performed a linear regression(OLS) using statsmodels.formula.api and showing the paramenters and summary the following way:

```
 result = sm.ols(formula="items ~ views + price", data=nvo).fit()
 print result.params
```

This is very usefull but I would like to save the significance of a the coefficient of price in a variable, how can I acces the elements of the summary object? Specificly how can I save the R squared, significance and the confidence interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I managed to answer my own question.
You just have to go ahead and do the following:

```
print result.pvalue
print result.conf_int()
print result.rsquared
```

Comment: Still figuring out the R squared